# How can I make wired internet connection work in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

It stopped working after the first software update.
I would be grateful if someone can help me fix this problem.

Running a System Test for networking only, the following results were obtained:

networking/detect PASSED

Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)

networking/internet FAILED

ERROR:root:Could not find def gateway info in /proc
ERROR:root:Could not find default gateway by running route

**$ /sbin/ifconfig** gives the following output:

```
lo  Link encap:Local Loopback    
    inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
    RX packets:2624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:2624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:195424 (195.4 KB) TX bytes:195424 (195.4 KB)


wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 6c:71:d9:8e:e7:ab
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**$ ip link** gives the following output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 6c:71:d9:8e:e7:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**$ lspci -v** gives the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915


00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd


00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
Memory at f7e1a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei
Kernel modules: mei


00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f7e18000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd


00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1c33
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at f7e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel


00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp


00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp


00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp


00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at f7e17000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd


00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt


00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
Memory at f7e16000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci


00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
Memory at f7e15000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c-i801


02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 1186
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Expansion ROM at f7d80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k


03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14c7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

**$lspci -nn -d 1969:** gives the following output:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
```

Comment: You seem to have lost the use of your driver, alx. Which output do you get after the second of these two commands? sudo rmmod alx        sudo modprobe alx

Comment: running $ sudo modprobe alx gave the following output: FATAL: Module alx not found. Could you please suggest how to re-install alx?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your ethernet card: lspci -nn -d 1969:  Do you have temporary use of wireless to install alx?

Comment: Result of command suggested by you added to post. And NO, I do not have access to a wireless connection, which is severely hampering me. I would be grateful if you could suggest an alternative. I can download packages on my other machine and copy them using a USB stick.

Comment: It can be done with great difficulty, for example, here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126&p=12206899#post12206899 You could instead download and install Ubuntu 13.10 and it would work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to download and compile the source code for the driver. First let us get something important,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Now we download, compile and install the driver:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/10/18/backports-20131018.tar.gz 
tar xvfz backports-20131018.tar.gz
cd backports-20131018
make defconfig-alx
make
sudo make install
```

Now we load the module:

```
sudo rmmod alx
sudo modprobe alx
```

and, hopefully, your ethernet should start working.